# How to make post request with active_admin_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to use this code in my active_admin page.

```
active_admin_form_for FeaturedPost.new, :url => '/', :method => :post
```

:url works fine, but it did not take :method. Still it is posting get request.

I want to use `active_admin_form_for` helper because of its nice representation of `has_many` fields with jquery.

Comment: Well that is strange. Are you sure `FeaturedPost.new` yields a new record, i.e. your FeaturedPost isn't saved right away by some wierd combination of initializers/callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

```
active_admin_form_for FeaturedPost.new, :url => '/', html: { method: :post }
```